# SAXON class loading problems in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, saxon

I have a dependencies problem in my Eclipse RCP application which I don't know how to resolve it properly.

I have a plugin "A" which has a class in charge of executing a XSLT transformations and has a dependency to net.sf.saxon (9.1.0) and bundle "B".

```
...
Bundle-Name: A
Require-Bundle: net.sf.saxon;bundle-version="[9.1.0,9.1.1)", B
...
```

On the other side, I have a plugin "B" which has a class "InformationProvider" that offers static methods to be called from a XSLT transformation process. Therefore this plugin defines a buddy policy in its manifest to allow Saxon using its classes.

```
...
Bundle-Name: B
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: net.sf.saxon
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: registered
...
```

The class in plugin "B":

```
package com.b.information;
...
public final class InformationProvider {
...
    public static String getSystemVersion() {
         return "1.0";
    }
...
}
```

The following is the content of XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:myUtil="java:com.b.information.InformationProvider">
 <xsl:template match="/">  
  <html>
   <p><h1>System Information</h1></p>   
   <p><h3>Version:</h3> <xsl:value-of select="myUtil:getSystemVersion()"/></p>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As described, when I execute a transformation of the previous XSLT from plugin "A" all works fine, and the generated HTML shows the version correctly.

However, I would like to get rid of the dependency from plugin "A" to plugin "B" since it can prone to dependency cycles in a future. When removing the dependency, SAXON is unable to find the class "InformationProvider".

Final question: Is it possible to make the classes of plugin "B" visible to SAXON without introducing a direct dependency between the plugins that use it?

Comment: Since Saxon, when executing your stylesheet, needs to find InformationProvider, that sounds to me like a dependency and I don't see how you can remove it. (But I don't know Eclipse at all well)

Comment: Could it be possible to indicate SAXON which class loader to use?

Comment: Now I remember, yes, Eclipse has rather specialised ClassLoader requirements. And indeed, Saxon allows it to be configured. You can do configuration.getDynamicLoader().setClassLoader(), or if you want you can write your own subclass of net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicLoader, register it using configuration.setDynamicLoader(), and then take care of the whole thing yourself.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for the reply. I'll try your proposal and comment the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Michael I was able to solve the problem.

What I did is to create a new plugin (SAXON wrapper) with the aim of:

1. Wrapping the Saxon libraries and offer the functionality of preforming XSLT transformation.
2. Provide an Extension point in order that other plugins can contribute with their class loaders.
3. Implement my own class loader that will act as a set of several class loaders (multi-class loader).

Plugins that have classes that must be accessible from XSLT transformation will contribute to the "Classloader" extension point of the new plugin by sending a reference to their class loader. In my case plugin "B".

Plugins that perform XSLT transformations will delegate this action to the new plugin. In my case plugin "A".

The SAXON wrapper plugin will collect all class loaders from all contributor plugins and will build a multi-class loader that will know about all contributor classes.

The SAXON wrapper plugin will always set a new configuration to the SAXON transformer factory which will include the multi-class loader like this:

```
// Retrieve the multi-class loader
Classloader multiClassloader = ClassLoaderProviderManager.getMultiClassLoader();
Configuration saxonConfiguration = new Configuration();
saxonConfiguration.getDynamicLoader().setClassLoader(multiClassloader);
```

With this solution I was able to remove ugly dependencies. Drawback is, that this approach will make visible to XSLT transformation all classes included in each contributor plugin.